# ESET uninstaller reset network settings

Tags: networking, uninstall

I used the ESET Uninstaller but it seems to have messed up my network settings - I now can't connect to our company network. Whenever I try it says:

> Unable to find domain controller for authentificating this user.

KB970326 and KB971234. How can I fix this?

Comment: Which product by Eset? NOD32 (just AV) or the Security Suite (Firewall also)?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the exact details of your system, it could be a whole host of problems.

Rather than fixing things piecemeal and praying that nothing else has been broken, I'd think about rolling the system to a backup or a System Restore point.  With software uninstallers, who knows what they have changed. . .

Answer (score 0):

With this being a domain system, were you supposed to have ESET installed, or be capable of uninstalling it?

I'd imagine the quickest way to resolve this would be to leave and then rejoin the domain. This would require that you have a local admin account on the computer, as your domain accounts would cease working once you left the domain.